# how to solve connection time out in ftp-gateway in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, ftp-client

thanks for attention
i used spring integration in spring project, my project is a simple file processing, get files from ftp with ftp adapter `int-ftp:outbound-gateway` and running batch jobs and put ouput files on ftp, i feel when file size or number of file that get from server was too large, thrown connection time out exception, my code as bellow:

```
   <int:inbound-channel-adapter expression="'/'" channel="inbound">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="${directory.server.polling.interval}"/>
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                                  session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                                  request-channel="inbound"
                                  command="ls"
                                  command-options="-R"
                                  expression="payload"
                                  reply-channel="inputFileSplitter"/>
    <bean id="splitter" class="com.ali.integration.handler.splitter.Splitter"/>
        <bean id="router" class="com.ali.integration.handler.router.Router"/>
        <int:splitter input-channel="inputFileSplitter" ref="splitter" method="inputFileSplitter" output-channel="FilesChannel"/>
        <int:channel id="FilesChannel"/>
        <int:router input-channel="FilesChannel" ref="router" method="routInputFile"/>
        <int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayGET"
                                  local-directory-expression="@fileUtil.backupRootPath + #remoteDirectory"
                                  session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                                  request-channel="readyToGetFilesChannel"
                                  reply-channel="readyFileToRemoveFromServerChannel"
                                  command="get"
                                  mode="REPLACE"
                                  command-options="-P"
                                  expression="payload.remoteDirectory + '/' + payload.filename"/>
```

it work business logic correctly ,but i feel when file size or number of file was too large. thrown the bellow exception:

```
2015-11-18 10:55:11.676 ERROR 6228 --- [ask-scheduler-5] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory; nested exception is org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.wrapExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:166)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:156)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:161)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:251)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:173)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory; nested exception is org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.get(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:811)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway$3.doInSession(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:534)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway$3.doInSession(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:530)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:410)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doGet(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:530)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:471)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:134)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1873)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.read(FtpSession.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.get(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:798)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.FromNetASCIIInputStream.read(FromNetASCIIInputStream.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.FromNetASCIIInputStream.read(FromNetASCIIInputStream.java:144)
    at org.apache.commons.net.io.Util.copyStream(Util.java:100)
    ... 79 more
```

and in ftp server log :

```
.  
    10/18/2015 11:10:47 AM - test (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's a network or server problem, there's nothing the framework can do to improve that.

You can try using wireshark or similar to trace the network traffic.